# Is there a way i can fix this ? i tried to copy the name of the package in the intent but it isn't working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, package

[image: Red Lines under the package when intenting]
Here I tried to copy the name of the package in the class part but apparently it isn't working please help

Answer (score 0):

as a second param for intent you should pass desired `Activity`s class, not package name

e.g. if you would want to open new instance of `MainActivity`:

```
new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.goaltracker.MainActivity.class);
```

in fact `com.example.goaltracker.` prefix isn't needed, you may just import desired `Activity` class (`new Intent(MainActivity.this, DesiredActivity.class)`)

PS. NEVER post code/text as screenshot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.goaltracker.Class);
```

Use this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, goaltracker.Class);
```

And when you create an activity, the preference is to name the first caractere of the word in uppercase, for example : `GoalTracker.class`